# IIS 7.5 - HTTP Redirect and URL Rewrite

Tags: redirects, iis7, .net

my goal is to give the users a friendly url like appname-help which should point to a sharePoint wiki site where we create the help content, the SharePoint url is ugly and long, something like: http://myprojectportal/Companyname/ProjectCollection/appName/WikiName/Wiki%20Pages/Home.aspx

which of course nobody likes.

After having asked the Server guys to create a DNS entry like this: appname-help which points to my web server I am now trying to configure IIS to redirect to the long url, creating a web site and configuring the HTTP Redirect feature it works fine but after redirect in the browser I still see the long old url while I would like IE and other browsers to keep showing the short friendly url appname-help even if the redirect has been done and the content comes from the SharePoint.

What else should I configure in the web.config or should I use the additional URL Rewrite module available here: http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite?

since I am redirecting to SharePoint site and not to a custom ASP.NET web application I have no global.asax nor any .NET C# file to edit only web.config and IIS settings for the redirect website to play with...

Comment: I think you'll need URL rewrite, [here's blog post which could help](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx)